# Implementing organic list browsing using arrow keys and intelligent lazy loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, settimeout

**Simple Scenario**

I have a list, i implemented browsing with the arrow keys (up, down) and on each change of the current list item, a database object gets loaded via AJAX.

Sweet.

**The Problem**

When a user browses through the list very fast, i don't want every request to go off. But the original request should go off instantly, of course.

My idea was to set a timeout using a variable as delay, and after the initial load of an item, increase that variable.

That works, but when the user stops browsing for a short moment, but then continues, i still don't want every request to go off.

So i figured, the delay variable must be reasonably increased with every browsing event, until a threshold is reached.

This organic approach would successfully minimize the amount of unnecessary loading of items.

**My Solution**

I came far. This piece of code (explanations below) will do the job, with one **major culprit**:

After the first time browsing is done and then stopped, the delay will automatically stay at a (2nd step) minimum value of 150ms.

Of course i tried to fix this, but as you will see, this is an interesting yet probably fairly common logical problem – and i think my overall approach is wrong.

But i don't see how. Brain does not compute. Computer says no.

**Code**

You can either sift through my given example or [go here for a fully functional simulator in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tonnqo0h/1/).

If you choose the jsFiddle:

Click the button, the item load appears immediately. Now wait a bit, click the button again, the initial load will be delayed. If you continuously press the button quickly, the item load will appear only when you're finished with your click-spree.

**Code Sample**

We're inside an object literal, just so you know.

```
_clickTimer: false,                     // holds what setTimeout() returns
_timerInc: 0,                           // the your timer delay are belong to us

/**
 * Function is triggered whenever the user hits an arrow key
 * itemRef is the passed list item object (table row, in this case)
 */

triggerItemClick: function(itemRef){

    var that=this;
    var itemId=$(itemRef).data('id');   // Get the item id

    if(this._clickTimer){               // If a timeout is waiting

        clearTimeout(this._clickTimer); // we clear it
        this._itemClickTimer=false;     // and reset the variable to false

        /**
         * Note that we only arrive here after the first call
         * because this._clickTimer will be false on first run
         */

        if(this._timerInc == 0){        // If our timer is zero
            this._timerInc = 150;       // we set it to 150
        } else {                        // otherwise
            if(this._timerInc <= 350)   // we check if it is lower than 350 (this is our threshold)
                this._timerInc += 15;   // and if so, we increase in steps of 15
        }

    } 

    /**
     * Regardless of any timing issues, we always want the list
     * to respond to browsing (even if we're not loading an item.
     */

    this.toggleListItem(itemId);

    /**
     * Here we now set the timeout and assign it to this._clickTimer
     */

    this._clickTimer=setTimeout(function(){

        // we now perform the actual loading of the item
        that.selectItem(itemId);

        // and we reset our delay to zero
        that._timerInc=0;

    }, this._timerInc); // we use the delay for setTimeout()

}
```

**Explanation**

On first call: `_clickTimer` is `false`, `_timerInc` is `0`, so the first call will lead to a delay of `0` for `setTimeout()` and `_clickTimer` will be set. The item will be instantly loaded.

Second call - given that our timeout is still waiting to be triggered, the `_clickTimer` gets cleared, the delay set to `150` if `0` or increased by `15` if lower than `350` (threshold).

This works great if you keep browsing. The timer increases, the load only gets fired once you stop browsing for a good moment.

**But** after you stopped, the next time you continue, `_clickTimer` will **not be false** (because `setTimeout()` assigns a counter to it), so in turn `_timerInc` will be set to `150` right away. So the first browse will lead to a delay of 150ms before anything gets loaded.

Call me crazy or fastidious, but the goal is to not have this delay.

Of course you'll say: simple, set `_clickTimer` to false at the end of the `setTimeout()` closure, so it gets reset once browsing is done and an item gets loaded. Great, but this results in the delay never going above 0ms. Think it through, you'll see.

I hope this was explained properly and that someone's brain is more capable of finding a solution to this than mine.

Comment: Sounds like you want some sort of cancellable future/promise...

Comment: Why don't you just store the AJAX call and cancel it when a new call is made and the previous call has not been finished?

Comment: (1) It shifts the problem (or solution) to a module/part of code has nothing to do with it per sé. (2) the approach does not allow for any "organic" UI-experience whatsoever, (3) it can (hypothetically) bottleneck performance and (4) it will lead to tons of cancelled requests, which means there already a stream of data, which is what needs to be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably possible to do this in a very sophisticated manner using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Since that is mostly sugar coating, I however thought that it must be possible to fix this directly, and I think I did.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tonnqo0h/3/). I added the delay in text, so it was easier for me to debug stuff, and also did some minor tidying up, but my actual changes are very small. This is detailed below.

Your remark near the end was my first intuition:

> Of course you'll say: simple, set `_clickTimer` to false at the end of
>   the `setTimeout()` closure, so it gets reset once browsing is done and
>   an item gets loaded. Great, but this results in the delay never going above 0ms.

Indeed, this would make it so that the delay would never get above 0, because, well, we cannot click that fast (or browse that fast, in your actual application). But... what if **we only reset if the delay was not 0**? So, if the timeout goes off, but it went off after only 0 milliseconds, we remember that there was a timeout. If it went off later than that, then an actual pause in the browsing must have occurred. This is implemented easily, by adding a couple of lines in the timeout callback as follows.

```
this._clickTimer = setTimeout(function() {

  // we now perform the actual loading of the item
  that.selectItem();

  // and we reset our delay to zero
  if (that._timerInc > 0) {
    that._clickTimer = false;
  }
  that._timerInc = 0;

}, this._timerInc); // we use the delay for setTimeout()
```

It seems to work exactly as you want it to, except that now, the delay will be 0ms, then 150ms, then 0ms, et cetera, if you wait between clicks long enough. This can be addressed by adding an extra timeout in case the delay *is* 0ms that will still reset the delay. Whenever a trigger happens (click in the demo, browsing in your app), this timeout is cancelled.

That together makes everything work the way you want it to, I believe. For completeness, I also include the above mentioned fiddle as a snippet here.

```js
var _simulator = {

  _clickTimer: false, // holds what setTimeout() returns
  _cancelClickTimer: false,
  _timerInc: 0, // the your timer delay are belong to us

  /**
   * Function is triggered whenever the user hits an arrow key
   * itemRef is the passed list item object (table row, in this case)
   */
  triggerItemClick: function() {

    var that = this;
    
    // always cancel resetting the timing, it can never hurt
    clearTimeout(that._cancelClickTimer);
    that._cancelClickTimer = false;

    if (this._clickTimer) { // If a timeout is waiting
      clearTimeout(this._clickTimer); // we clear it
      this._clickTimer = false; // and reset the variable to false

      /**
       * Note that we only arrive here after the first call
       * because this._clickTimer will be false on first run
       */
      if (this._timerInc == 0) { // If our timer is zero
        this._timerInc = 150; // we set it to 150
      } else { // otherwise
        if (this._timerInc <= 350) // we check if it is lower than 350 (this is our threshold)
          this._timerInc += 15; // and if so, we increase in steps of 15
      }
    }

    /**
     * Regardless of any timing issues, we always want the list
     * to respond to browsing (even if we're not loading an item.
     */
    this.toggleListItem();

    /**
     * Here we now set the timeout and assign it to this._clickTimer
     */
    this._clickTimer = setTimeout(function() {

      // we now perform the actual loading of the item
      that.selectItem();

      // and we reset our delay to zero
      if (that._timerInc > 0) {
       that._clickTimer = false;
      } else {
       that._cancelClickTimer = setTimeout(function() {
         that._clickTimer = false;
        }, 150);
      }
      that._timerInc = 0;

    }, this._timerInc); // we use the delay for setTimeout()

  },

  /** the following functions are irrelevant for the problemsolving above **/

  toggleListItem: function() {
    $('#status').prepend($('<div />').text('You toggled a list item ... in ' + this._timerInc + ' ms'));
  },

  selectItem: function(id) {
    $('#loader').show();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#loader').hide();
    }, 800);
  }

};

$('#clickZone').on('click', function() {
  _simulator.triggerItemClick();
});
```

```css
#clickZone {
  background: #369;
  color: #fff;
  width: 420px;
  height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#status {
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #936;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 7px 10px;
}

#status > div {
  padding: 2px 0 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
}

#status > div:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

#loader,
#notice {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 320px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}

#notice {
  background: lightblue;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clickZone">
  CLICK ME TO SIMULATE LIST BROWSING
</div>
<div id="loader">
  &#10003; &nbsp;Browsing ended, loading item!
</div>
<div id="status">
  <div>
    Waiting for something to happen ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts! I appreciate it! I was excited to check your fiddle but i see a problem: when i continue (simulating) browsing, after i previously stopped, the load will go off on the first browse event (which it shouldn't). It should only go off once browsing has finished. Perhaps the 800ms timeout on the load indicator accounts for that, because in the simulator you don't get to see so clearly, when a load is actually happening. I have updated the fiddle to allow for a simulation that is less prone to such problems: https://jsfiddle.net/tonnqo0h/4/

Comment: I see your point, but I thought this would be desired behavior. You want to respond immediately on the first browsing event and when there is a whole spree, you wait until the spree is over.
You cannot both respond immediately and wait to see if there will be another event at the same time.
The only thing you can do is cancel an AJAX request that was fired, if applicable.
Alternatively, you can reset the time to something small, like 50ms, instead of 0ms. But then your initial solution would be adequate.

Comment: @SquareCat You should have updated your question with the new jsFiddle. Better, you should have answered your question yourself. Leaving the old stuff around is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want at least 100ms between each request, but if the last request was more than 100ms ago, the data should be fetched immediately.

The following should do the trick (pseudo code):

First, create the following variables (those need to be accessible from the functions below)

```
delayLoad       // (boolean) - initial false
currentItem     // initial 1
lastItemFetched // initial 1
```

On first pageload, item 1 should be shown (with 'item' meaning one big item per page, or a full page of rows -- if item should be one row on 20 row pages some extra code will be needed to keep track of which rows need to be fetched -- but obviously, when the user keeps pressing the down button while the timer (delay) is running, at least the internal position should be changing, to give a feeling of faster scrolling).

```
OnArrowDown:
    currentItem++ // and check boundaries
    getData()
OnArrowUp:
    currentItem-- // and check boundaries
    getData()

getData()
    if not delayLoad
        getRealData()
    // else do nothing

getRealData()
    delayLoad = true
    lastItemFetched = currentItem // currentItem could change while
                                  // data is being fetched
    get itemdata for lastItemFetched from server
    on receive
        update data on page for lastItemFetched
        set 100ms timer 

onTimer
    if currentItem != lastItemFetched
        getRealData()
    else
        delayLoad = false
```

If you really want a longer delay if the user keeps scrolling fast, you can do this:

```
delayLoad       // (boolean) - initial false
currentItem     // initial 1
lastItemFetched // initial 1
changeCount     // initial 0

OnArrowDown:
    currentItem++ // and check boundaries
    getData()
OnArrowUp:
    currentItem-- // and check boundaries
    getData()

getData()
    changeCount++
    if not delayLoad
        getRealData()
    // else do nothing

getRealData()
    delayLoad = true
    lastItemFetched = currentItem // currentItem could change while
                                  // data is being fetched
    get itemdata for lastItemFetched from server
    on receive
        update data on page for lastItemFetched
        set timer to 100 + changeCount * 5 // or some other number
                                 // and maybe set a max value for the total
        changeCount = 0

onTimer
    if currentItem != lastItemFetched
        getRealData()
    else
        delayLoad = false
```

To speed up scrolling even more - say there are a million items and the user keeps holding down the down arrow, you could do something like this:

```
OnArrowDown:
    currentItem++ // and check boundaries
    if changeCount > some_value // user keeps holding down the button
        currentItem += changeCount * some_factor // check boundaries
    getData()
```

But you would have to do something extra inside `getRealData()` where `changeCount` is reset to 0.

This could be combined with updating the `currentItem` number on the page in real time.

---

Alternatively you could fetch multiple items at once and store them in a local cache.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, that you cannot detect a second keypress after the very first one. A delay schema of 0, 150, 165, ... 350ms is unrealistic, since real requests take a real amount of time (not 0ms).

Detecting a keypress within a certain time span is one possible solution. It proceeds from 0 to 150ms delay, if a second keypress is detected within 100ms.

```
_clickTimer: false,
_timerInc: 0,

// When was the last trigger action (ms)
_lastTriggerTime: 0,

// Time span after first trigger event, during which the _timerInc
// is advanced.
_initRestartInterval: 100,

// Time span after last trigger event, during which the _timerInc
// is advanced.
_currentRestartInterval: 100,

triggerItemClick: function(itemRef){

    var that=this;
    var itemId=$(itemRef).data('id');

    if(this._clickTimer){
        clearTimeout(this._clickTimer);
        this._clickTimer = false;
    }

    var _triggerTime = new Date().getTime();
    var _elapsed = _triggerTime - this._lastTriggerTime;
    this._lastTriggerTime = _triggerTime;

    if (_elapsed > this._currentRestartInterval) {
        this._timerInc = 0;
        this._currentRestartInterval = this._initRestartInterval;
    } else {
        if(this._timerInc == 0){
            this._timerInc = 150;
        } else {
            if(this._timerInc <= 350)
                this._timerInc += 15;
        }
        this._currentRestartInterval = this._timerInc;
    }

    this.toggleListItem(itemId);

    this._clickTimer=setTimeout(function(){

        // we now perform the actual loading of the item

        // :ws: And here is the problem with a simulation that
        // does not take any relevant time at all.

        // If _clickTimer is set to false, before the "loading"
        // has taken a noticable amount of time, the early reset
        // problem arises and _timerInc is always 0.
        that.selectItem(itemId);

        // In an asynchronous environment, the following should
        // take place in the result handler.
        if (that._timerInc > 0) {
            // next trigger event will reset _timerInc to 0
            that._lastTriggerTime = 0;
        }

    }, this._timerInc);
}
```

Here is a version, which properly simulates a data request. It behaves exactly like the version with time measurement for the first click: However, for further clicks, it behaves differently, because each delay has another 100ms of request time added. This makes the delays effectively 100, 250, 265, ... 450ms.

```
_clickTimer: false,
_timerInc: 0,

// Is there still a request for data?
_pendingRequest: false,

triggerItemClick: function(itemRef){

    var that=this;
    var itemId=$(itemRef).data('id');

    var tooFast = this._clickTimer || this._pendingRequest;

    if(this._clickTimer){
        clearTimeout(this._clickTimer);
        this._clickTimer = false;
    }

    // asynchronous AJAX request simulated with a timer
    if(this._pendingRequest){
        clearTimeout(this._pendingRequest);
        this._pendingRequest = false;
    }

    if (! tooFast) {
        this._timerInc = 0;
    } else {
        if(this._timerInc == 0){
            this._timerInc = 150;
        } else {
            if(this._timerInc <= 350)
                this._timerInc += 15;
        }
    }

    this.toggleListItem(itemId);

    this._clickTimer=setTimeout(function(){

        // we now perform the actual loading of the item
        // :ws: assuming it will take 100ms
        that._pendingRequest = setTimeout(function(){
            that.selectItem(itemId);
            that._pendingRequest = false;
        }, 100);

        that._clickTimer = false;

    }, this._timerInc);
}
```